# "Brace for something" - is the phrase "brace for" usually positive? Or is it neutral in this case?

Tags: phrase-usage

> WASHINGTON (AP) — Donald Trump and his allies are escalating efforts
> to undermine the criminal case against him and drum up protests as the
> former president **braces for a history-making federal court appearance**
> this week on dozens of felony charges accusing him of illegally
> hoarding classified information.

[Source: AP](https://apnews.com/article/trump-indictment-russia-justice-department-special-counsel-3e0c8e5d2ccc35fcb249f6f37f79be81)

The phrase "brace for" sounds, to me, as if it has a positive meaning. In the case above, does it simply sound neutral? Or does it always sound neutral in any circumstance?

Comment: What do you mean by "positive" and "neutral" here? It's obvious from the overall tone of your cited source that the *writer* has a very negative opinion of Trump, so presumably from their perspective, it's a "good" thing that Trump is being attacked - which he metaphorically braces himself for, which will please the writer (especially if the attack is so strong Trump can't withstand it even by bracing himself).

Comment: You're wrong: it's extremely negative. "Brace for impact" and so on.

Comment: @NewPlanet unfortunately the answer you have accepted is incorrect

Comment: I only know the term in a negative context. You "brace for" bad things to happen, and if you "brace for it" you are merely trying to mitigate impact, not turn it into something positive.

Comment: Adding to my earlier comment, the sole positive use of "brace" is when an experience is described as "bracing": this particularly applies to stormy weather as in the classic advertising hoarding (seen at least until the 1970s) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jolly_Fisherman

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Is the phrase "brace for" usually positive? Or is it neutral in this case?**

The answer to your question is more complex than you might hope. It might be simpler to believe that "to brace for" isn't positive, negative, or neutral. The words don't apply because *bracing against impact* or *bracing against change* is something you do when you know the impact or the change is coming. Not unlike shutting a door is something you do with a door — it's not positive, negative, or neutral.

**When can bracing be perceived as positive, negative or neutral?**

The idea of bracing being positive, negative or neutral relates to the *purpose* or *consequence* for bracing, just as it would in regard to shutting a door.

- Are you shutting out a potential invader? Then it's a good thing to do (positive).
- Are you shutting the door on a friend who didn't intend to offend you? Then it's a bad thing to do (negative).
- Are you simply shutting the door because it's open and it's natural condition is to be closed? Then it's neither good nor bad (neutral).

Bracing against impact or change (meaning, in the case of your question, "to prepare for impact or change") is usually perceived as a good thing (positive) because we tend to believe that preparing for something is always a good thing to do. However, even a good thing taken too far can become a bad thing. If we "brace ourselves against offense" by shutting everyone out of our lives, that's usually a bad (negative) thing.

Muddying the problem is that the word and its common phrase are often used metaphorically, as in the case of the article from the Associated Press. When used in this manner, the purpose of the word or phrase is to give the reader an idea of the *size of the problem* or the *enormity of the impact* (e.g., one doesn't usually brace for a sprinkling of rain, but would always brace for a hurricane). Thus, the author of the article used the phrase to imply a *great change* or a *severely difficult time* was coming for Mr. Trump. This implies *something undesirable* and would normally be interpreted as something negative — but that still depends on your point of view. When the United States was considering the issue of Same Sex Marriage back in 2013, the nation braced itself for change. The change wasn't negative, it was certainly good, but the *effort to embrace the change* was going to be *uncomfortable* (in the least!) and that discomfort (which is still happening) could be perceived as negative — even if, by some, the discomfort is perceived as deserved.

And that underscores the complexity of determining positive, negative, or neutral. Because it's possible for Mr. Trump to be imprisoned as a result of the trial, representing an enormous impact to or change in his lifestyle, which would be negative *to him* and so bracing for that change would be a positive *for him.* Some, on the other hand, believe he is guilty and deserves what he gets. They would see the guilty verdict and Mr. Trump's incarceration as a positive and the act of bracing for the trial as negative.

**My father-in-law maintains that anything growing where it doesn't belong is a weed**

As I said, the idea of "bracing for" an impact or change really isn't positive, negative or neutral. It's simply something one does when a force (literal or metaphorical) that must be survived is known to be approaching. Whether or not the action was positive, negative, or neutral depends on context, perspective, and expectations.

A flower, beautiful as it is but growing in the middle of your perfectly cut lawn, is a weed simply because it isn't wanted there. A flower growing in a flower bed isn't a weed simply because it is wanted there. If you allow for my imperfect metaphor, a flower is positive or negative because of where it grows, not because it's a flower.

Comment: This seems a bit like arguing that "success" can be negative, if it's someone you don't like doing the succeeding. From the perspective of the person doing the bracing, it's always to prepare for something with at least some negative aspects. The act of bracing indicates that the person doing the bracing expects some negative effects. How anyone else views it is rather orthogonal to whether it'd be called "bracing" or not.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Of course I am. If a terrorist is successful, is that a positive? According to whom? If I brace myself for a financial windfall, are the effects expected to be negative? If I'm required to brace a vehicle frame due to a government standard that has no evidence of a problem (I've dealt with these...) is that a positive or a negative? No, I'm arguing that without context the act of bracing (literally or metaphorically) is none of those things. It's merely an act. Like shutting a door.

Comment: "According to whom?" - according to the subject of the sentence, otherwise nothing ever makes sense. The final result of following your logic would be that everything is both positive and negative at all times.

Comment: @JBH "Bracing for a financial windfall" implies that you expect negative consequences like a tax bill or money grubbing relatives - you don't brace for a strictly positive windfall like a birthday card with cash in it. If it's strictly positive, you wouldn't use the negative word "bracing", you'd use a more neutral term like "preparing". I don't understand your view that acts can't have positive/negative connotations themselves, "slamming" a door vs. "shutting" has a negative connotation, as does "trudging" vs. "walking" or "droning" vs. "talking".

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I would argue that precisely because the thing we brace for is overwhelmingly negative, the actual act of bracing for it is more or less inherently **positive**. The absence of bracing will have negative consequences, therefore bracing improves (or at least tries to improve) the net outcome, which makes it positive for the person doing the bracing.

Comment: @Davor Thank you for confirming that the point of my answer is that without context the idea of bracing is not positive, negative, or neutral. Unless, of course, you mean that in the sentence, "Terrorists today successfully set off a bomb, killing four people" means the word "success" is always in a positive context because the subject of the sentence was "terrorists."

Comment: @NuclearHoagie No, you are implying there's a negative consequence. Who's to say that, E.G., bracing for a hug has any negative consequence at all? You? The subject may be preparing for an event that's considered entirely enjoyable in every aspect. I'm curious how you'd interpret NASA's use of the phrase, "a successful failure" to describe the Apollo 13 mission. The answer's purpose is to address the OP's question about the use of a phrase in an AP article. I mention at the beginning of my answer that there are complexities (one being an oxymoron...).

Comment: @Davor I've been pondering your last sentence. It's entirely false. I'm not proposing that everything is positive[, neutral] **and** negative at all times. I'm specifically arguing that things are positive, neutral **or** negative depending on context. As I just hinted at in a comment to Nuclear Hoagie, if we don't permit this, then an oxymoron can't exist in our use of English. It's true that an oxymoron presupposes a "default" condition. But that's cultural, not grammatical. I suppose you could say that tightening a lug nut is inherently positive, but what's the point re. the OP's question?

Comment: I don't think I agree with this answer, or at the very least, it's confusingly written. For "Bracing against impact ... is usually perceived as a good thing ... because we tend to believe that preparing for something is always a good thing to do." Well, yes, but the phrase itself highlights the outside negative value of the impact. Secondly, "bracing" implies not so much preparation in terms of *adaption* but a steadfast refusal in an attempt to let the negative event blow past. When a town braces for a hurricane, it means there's nothing left to be done but duck and cover and pray.

Comment: Or, it's a bit philosophical for an ELL answer. The phrase itself is used when something bad is happening to someone, and they are not adapting to it, but pushing back. **I don't think it has a positive valence in the sense that the bracer is being complimented for their ability to adapt.** It would also be improved by discussing the physical meaning of brace, and then turning to the metaphorical. Which yes, they're different but it's kinda unclear to follow.

Comment: @JBH Nobody’s saying that bracing has negative consequences (they should be positive); it’s the thing you brace _for_ that is negative. ‘Bracing’ for a hug means you consider the hug undesirable (perhaps it’s from a particularly loathed great-aunt). The fact that the same action/event can be seen as positive or negative depending on the viewpoint does not change the fact that using the word ‘brace’ means that **the person doing the bracing considers the thing being braced against to be negative**. If you’re bracing for a lottery win, then for some reason you don’t want that win.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- "The phrase ... is used when something bad is happening to someone." That may be common, but it isn't universally true.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet `‘Bracing’ for a hug means you consider the hug undesirable` That's an assumption you're stating as fact and isn't true outside of context, which can include the use of the phrase as an oxymoron or an emphatic. The assertion that bracing for a lottery win means you don't want that win is breathtakingly ridiculous. The phrase can mean nothing more than making preparations with the help of an accountant - something the potential winner had perhaps never done before or to an extent that was unusual. There's nothing *negative* about it.

Comment: @JBH So far, you’re the only person here – and indeed, the only person I’ve ever come across – who understands or uses _brace for_ in this way. You are stating as fact your assumption that the thing you’re bracing for is essentially neutral, which is simply not true. That is not what the word means. **Any** word can be used oxymoronically or ironically to take on a different meaning from what it usually means, but the default meaning is required to understand such usage. Bracing for a lottery win is such a usage; the implication is that even positives like winning the lottery have negative →

Comment: → aspects (like taxes, legal mires, having to get lawyers), so you steel yourself for having to deal with that. It is still based on the fact that the object of _brace for_ (or _brace against_, for that matter) is inherently seen as something negative coming towards you; using the word ironically does not change this.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for making my point. *Why* you brace determines positive or negative. "To brace" is neither positive nor negative. Bracing is a negative if you do it (or had to do it) for no good reason. It's a positive if you do it (or had to do it) for a good reason. The fact that I'm the only person you've met who thinks this way may speak more to your limited exposure to humanity than my error. And lest we get too far off-topic, the answer was selected as the most useful to the OP - and the point here is to address the OP's needs. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I did not make your point; but your last comment rather makes mine (since bracing without reason makes no sense). Note that my scope of ‘people’ not only includes a lifetime of experience of English speakers (including all those who have disagreed outright with you here), but also dictionaries, all of which explicitly state that bracing is done against something difficult or unpleasant – i.e., negative. The OP’s choice means nothing – it’s literally a choice by someone _who doesn’t know_ (hence the question), and incorrect choices are not a new thing.

Answer (score 34):

The literal meaning of "brace" in this context is to prepare for a force so that you don't move. Like, if you're driving a car and you're going to get hit from behind, you might push the steering wheel hard so that you don't fly forward after the impact. This is bracing yourself.

More figuratively, it means "prepare for impact" of any kind. Nobody is going to literally hit Trump in court, but it won't be pleasant for him.

To "brace for" something almost always implies something negative like a physical collision or attack, or a figurative one, like a court appearance.

Rarely it implies something neutral or even pleasant but shocking, like if you jump into a freezing cold lake for fun, you'd likely brace yourself against the sudden chill.

Comment: _Almost_ always negative, sometimes neutral. I could see bracing for a tough challenge you're well-prepared and excited for, for instance.

Comment: I don't know if this is an authoritative source: _Miss World hopeful braced for success 14 November, 2014  A Miss World contestant has flown halfway across the world for pioneering cosmetic dental treatment in Edinburgh, ahead of taking part in the global beauty pageant in London in December._ Scottish Dental Magazine

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I think there's a bit of cheap wordplay going on there… dental work… braces…

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - er, yes. I didn't spot that!

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - I am not a regular reader of dental journals!

Comment: It's usually negative, but it could be sort of positive. What if your 3 year old kid is rushing at you to give you a hug, and you brace yourself so you don't get knocked over?

Comment: I could see using "brace for" in a situation where one is expecting a pleasant surprise. The implication being that you might faint from excitement, so you need to be prepared for the emotional shock of the positive news: "Brace yourself ... you just won a million dollars!"

Comment: Another well-known example of the word is on commercial airlines, where the flight attendants will instruct passengers to _adopt the ‘brace’ position_ when they hear the words _“Brace! Brace!”_

Comment: @the-baby-is-you Thanks! I've modified my answer

Comment: @the-baby-is-you I feel like if an event is overall good or neutral, "bracing" is always for the negative parts. Like if someone is bracing themselves for a trip to Denny's, it means we're about to be told something they don't like about it. Or in PeterFlom's example, they've braced for the knocked over part, not the hug.

Comment: Bracing is not just about impacts. It applies to structural elements. Diagonal bracing, etc. There is no negative connotation with bracing in that sense.

Comment: @user8356 Yes, there are several meanings of "brace". I'm only talking about the one in use here

Comment: @PeterFlom that's still a negative, because as you said yourself, you're bracing in order to not get knocked over.

Comment: Can also be used sarcastically(?) talking to someone about something you think/hope they will be delighted by. F.ex. "Have you heard the news? Brace yourself ... Liz Truss just resigned". (If the other person doesn't say something affirmative, you might have avoided offending them).